# Can we add the bundle product in bundle product items for bundle product?

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, bundled-product, magento2.4.4, bundle

Is this possible to add the bundle product in bundle product items for bundle product?

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try these steps, hope it will work ?

1. Create the parent bundle product in Magento 2.
2. In the "Bundle Items" section of the parent product, click "Add Option" and choose "Bundle".
3. Configure the child bundle product as a bundle item, selecting the appropriate options, quantities, and prices.
4. Save the parent bundle product.

Once the parent bundle product is saved, the child bundle product will be listed as a bundle item, along with any other products or options that have been added.

Comment: choose "Bundle" - Bundle is not coming after clicking the "Add Option" @Navneet Sharma
configure and bundle products is not showing under the "Add product to option"'s Grid